# The concept of correlation in functional analysis

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, correlation

I am currently reading a book "measure, integral and probability" by Capinski and Kopp. The correlation between random variables $X$ and $Y$ is defined as the cosine of the angle between $X_c$ and $Y_c$, that is:
$$
\operatorname{corr(X,Y)} = \frac{(X_c,Y_c)}{(\|X\|\cdot\|Y\|)},
$$
where $X_c$, $Y_c$ are centered random variables defined by $X_c=X-\mathbb{E}(X)$, $Y_c=Y-\mathbb{E}(Y)$.
The question that immediately arises is:
Why do we divide by $\|X\|\cdot\|Y\|$, and not $\|X_c\|\cdot\|Y_c\|$?

I want to understand the concept of correlation, independence and other concepts of probability from the point of view of functional analysis. I would be very happy if you could recommend some literature that has a treatment of this topic, and desirably, detailed discussion of the following questions: Are uncorrelated variables just orthogonal? or only if $\mathbb{E}(X)=0=\mathbb{E}(Y)$? How is the "centred" vector different from original, "geometrically"? I know in infinite dimenstions it is hard to visualise geometry, but still... Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe that it *should* be $\|X_c\|\|Y_c\|$, not $\|X\| \|Y\|$. See for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Definition

Comment: I agree with @Bungo; see also [this](http://brenocon.com/blog/2012/03/cosine-similarity-pearson-correlation-and-ols-coefficients/) for more details.